# Stretching a div horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve a layout like this:

[image]

where following conditions are always satisfied (irrespective of browser width):

1. Div1 and Div2 have equal heights (50%)
2. Div 3 has a fixed width (50px).
3. Div1 should fill the whole remaining width.
4. Div4 is of fixed height (100px) and width (30px) and always in centre to the Div3 (horizontal

and vertical)

I do not want to use the CSS3 `flex` based display due to its unavailability on old browser. I tried to use the `display:inline-block`, but that does not stretch Div1 as desired. How can I achieve this layout without using javascript? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the structure you're looking for by utilizing the power of [containing blocks](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details). An element with on of [`position:relative`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#relative-positioning) [`position:absolute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#absolute-positioning)  [`position:fixed`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#fixed-positioning) will form a new containing block for any `position:absolute` children.

You can center `div4` with [`display:inline-block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#display-prop), [`vertical-align:middle`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) and a helper element.

See the comments in the code below for an explanation of what each property's use is in this example.

This solution will work for all major browsers [except IE <= 7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing)

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qmzjL2uk/))

```css
#wrp {
    height: 100%;           /* All of the container's height */
    position: relative;     /* Establish a containing block */
}
#wrp > #top, 
#wrp > #bottom {
    position: absolute;     /* Absolutely relative to #wrp */
    height: 50%;            /* Half of #wrp's height */
    width: 100%;            /*  All of #wrp's width  */
}
#bottom {
    bottom: 0;              /* Move the bottom half to the bottom of #wrp */
}
#top > #left, 
#top > #right {
    position: absolute;     /* Absolutely relative to #top */
    height: 100%;           /* All of #top's height */
}
#left {
    left: 0;                /* Stick #left to the left of #top */
    right: 50px;            /* Expand #left to 50px from the right of #top */
}
#right {
    right: 0;               /* Stick #right to the right of #top */
    width: 100%;            /* Make #right's width responsive */
    max-width: 50px;        /* Limit #right's width to 50px */
    padding: 10px;          /* Horizontally center the child */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Padding included in width */
    font-size: 0;           /* Remove white-space between elements */
}
#center-helper,
#inner {
    display: inline-block;  /* vertical-align applies to inline and inline-block
                               sizing applies to inline-block but not inline */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Align #inner to the center of the helper */
    height: 100%;           /* #center-helper will always be full height
                               #inner will be responsive, see next rule */
}
#inner {
    max-height: 100px;      /* Limit height to 100px */
    width: 100%;            /* Parent width = 50px + padding (10px*2) = 30px */
    font-size: 12pt;        /* Restore font size from the previous fix */
}

/* Colours and environment */
html,body{height:100%;margin:0}#bottom{background:#00b35e}#left{background:#ff000b}#right{background:#fff900}#inner{background:#00b1f5}
```

```html
<div id="wrp">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="left">
        </div>
        <div id="right"> 
            <!-- IE6&7 inline-block only applies to inline elements -->
            <span id="center-helper"></span>
            <span id="inner"></span>         
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution ( IE support is IE >= 9 ):

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
    height: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

.half-height {
    height: 100%;
}

.red {
    background-color: red
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.blue {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin: 0px 10px; /* 50px - 30px = right & left margins */
}

.green {
    background-color: green
}

/* Use tables to vertically center the blue box */
.vertical-center {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.vertical-container {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="red half-height"></div>
    <div class="yellow half-height">
        <div class="vertical-center">
            <div class="vertical-container">
                <div class="blue"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="green half-height"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2jtu1rsn/1/

Vertical centering technique was taken from here:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Answer (score 1):

The CSS3 `calc()` function is good candidate for this:

```
#div3 {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
}

#div1 {
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Here's an [example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPXzWL).

Comment: Unfortunately it won't. For future reference, [this site](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is the go-to for compatibility information.  I believe there is a way to do this without `calc()` and without JavaScript (that doesn't force you into using `absolute`, but it's very hacky and I'm struggling to remember how.

Comment: Really? Downvoted? Care to explain why? This answer is one of the best cross-browser solutions without JavaScript, hands down.

Answer (score 1):

Position with absolutes and without calc. Enjoy the updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/5smIkzvI4163tfYmXr1S?p=preview).

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.div1, .div2, .div3, .div4 {
  position: absolute;
}

.div1, .div3 {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}

.div1 {
  right: 50px;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.div2 {
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: green;
}

.div3 {
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}

.div4 {
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  margin: -50px -15px 0 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
.div1 {
    background: red;
    height: 50%;
}
.div2 {
    background: green;
    height: 50%;
}
.div3 {
    background: yellow;
    height: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}

.div4{
    height: 100px;
    width: 30px;
    background: blue;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="div3">
        <div class="div4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="div1"></div>
    <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```